# getting stuck after sending async request to node.js server

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await, sendasynchronousrequest

I have tried it in console application

```
public async Task<string> Getsmth(string a, string b, string c, HttpClient client)
{
string str = "call to node.js"
var response = await client.GetStringAsync(str);
return response;
}
```

calling it in console application worked greatly, but after calling same code in web api it got stuck in await line

```
[Route("api/Getsmth/{a}/{b}/{c}")]
public string Get(string a, string b, string c)
{
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
 var r = Getsmth(a, b, c, client);
return r.Result;
}
```

after calling it synchronously (without async/await) everything works fine. what seems to be the problem?! How to make it work asynchronously?

Comment: When you say you call it without async/await, are you still returning a task?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your api action to return a `Task<IHttpActionResult>`, then await `Getsmth`, like this:

```
[Route("api/Getsmth/{a}/{b}/{c}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(string a, string b, string c)
{
   HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
   var r = await Getsmth(a, b, c, client);
   return Ok(r);
 }
```

You could return `Task<string>` from `Get` as well, then just `return r` instead instead of `Ok(r)`:

```
[Route("api/Getsmth/{a}/{b}/{c}")]
public async Task<string> Get(string a, string b, string c)
{
   HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
   var r = await Getsmth(a, b, c, client);
   return r;
 }
```